# How to retrieve list of XML Nodes using SelectNode() WITHOUT attributes?

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse out a simple list of strings from an XML file. I only want to retrieve the values that do NOT have a specified attribute.

For example, in this XML snippet:

```
<meaning>sultry</meaning>
<meaning>hot</meaning>
<meaning>summer heat</meaning>
<meaning m_lang="fr">chaud</meaning>
<meaning m_lang="fr">torride</meaning>
...
```

Calling `SelectNodes("//meaning")` will return sultry, hot, summer heat, chaud, torride. However, I only want to retrieve the values labeled only `<meaning>`, not `<meaning m_lang="fr>`, i.e. I only want to have sultry, hot, summer heat.

Is there a simple method to only retrieve the non-attribute values? They will always be the first in the list, but there may be a single value, or multiple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to make your [XPath Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp) (the string you're passing to SelectNodes()) more specific. In this case, you want to find nodes without any additional attributes, so you modify your XPath expression like so:

```
SelectNodes("//meaning[not(@*)]")
```

To break the above down:

- "meaning" selects all "meaning" elements,
- "@*" selects all elements with at least one attribute,
- "not" negates a rule

So together this means "Select all 'meaning' elements that do not have at least one attribute" .

For further reference, check out this [nifty xpath cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath).

Comment: Wow, that was a fantastically simple solution and a helpful link. Thank you so much!